# Putty becomes inactive in middle of working on ec2 instance?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bower, putty

I have been using this code(https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-angular-cognito-sample) to authenticate my angular project via aws. I am running ec2 via putty and in between these putty suddenly becomes inactive.

Also after cloning this project and configuring angular CLI, apache and other dependencies required, When I try to run ng build it shows:
**The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found**.
but I am already inside my project folder.
Before you mention about the version of angular/cli. I have already updated that.